# Where would be better to handle an exception?

Tags: java, exception-handling

Imagine I have the following DAO method:

```
public Employee getEmployeeById(Integer id){
    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(getJdbcTemplate());
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :userId";
    Map<String, Object> parameterMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    parameterMap.put("userId", id);
    return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, parameterMap, new EmployeeRowMapper());// Throws 
                                                               //EmptyResultDataAccessException
}
```

The DAO method is used by the controller method:

```
public class EmployeeListController{

    @Resource(name = "employeeDAO")
    private EmployeeDAO employeeDAO;

    @RequestMapping(value="/{empId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getEmployeeById(@PathVariable String empId, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("employee", employeeDAO.getEmployeeById(Integer.valueOf(empId)));
        return "employeesList";
    }
}
```

Where would be better to handle the Exception? In the controller's method or the DAO's method? I think, that in the controller it would be, because otherwise we should return the Object with empty properties, which is not good. Is it correct?

Comment: No one will ever agree on where and what types of Exceptions (Checked/Unchecked) is the best pattern...

Comment: What does an EmptyResultDataAccessException mean? Does it mean that employee ID isn't in the database?

Comment: @raptortech97 Exactly.

Comment: `getEmployeeById` could return `null`, which could be interpreted as "no such employee in Db" by the caller. however, this means that you would have to handle the *same* error *twice* (once in the DAO  method, and a second time in the controller method), which isn't very efficient.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question "where would it be more appropriate to handle the exception" will depend on what your intended semantics are for the `getEmployeeByID` method.

In the .NET Framework, methods that semantically must never throw an exception are prefixed with Try, as in `Double.TryParse()`.  Usually, you pass a string to parse and a `ref` variable, and the function returns a boolean indicating success or failure.

In other words, if you handle the exception in the `getEmployeeByID` method, you must also return some status to the caller indicating whether the operation succeeded or not.

Since I don't see any evidence that your `getEmployeeByID` method returns something indicating success or failure, the semantics of your method dictate allowing the exception to pass to the caller. Ergo, you would handle the exception in the `EmployeeListController` class.

**Further Reading**
[Does Java have an int.TryParse that doesn't throw an exception for bad data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391979/does-java-have-a-int-tryparse-that-doesnt-throw-an-exception-for-bad-data)

Comment: The semantics do not suggest throwing some random database exception, though. If an exception is thrown, it should be relevant and informative.

Comment: @raptortech97: `EmptyResultDataAccessException` seems sufficiently descriptive.  You could catch that and rethrow some sort of custom `RecordNotFoundException`, but then you'd be adding another class for not much benefit.

Comment: Well, it could become a `NoSuchEmployeeID` exception, which is telling a bit more about the nature of the issue (from a code readability perspective), but if the exception can be discriminated unambiguously as it is, there's little gain in transforming it.

Comment: @didierc: Yeah, that would be incredibly specific for an exception; you would need *one exception class for every domain entity.*  As you may have guessed by now, I'm squarely in the "checked exceptions are not worth the effort" camp.

Comment: If you forget the previous (dumb and thus erased) comment I made, and imagine that exceptions in Java are not expensive objects anymore, would you more likely use them? Or do you actually refuse to use exceptions for other reasons?

Comment: @didierc: Expense is more than just performance; it is also complexity. Every new class that you put into a program is one more class that must be read, understood and maintained by your fellow programmers.  All other things being equal, the less code your program uses to accomplish its purpose, the better.